# Import data from database_source.mdb to database_destination.mdb

Tags: ruby, ms-access, sequel

I have an existing source MDB database and I need to programmatically import some tables into a destination MDB.

The first approach was to import table per table and, iterating each row, copy the record to the destination MDB Database.

This has some limitation because of the amount of data to copy, so, I found the `DB[:table_name].import` method in Ruby sequel, but I don't understand how it works.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
def import
    @table_fields = {
        :table_name = [:id, fiels_a, :field_b, :field_n]
    } 

    @db_source = Sequel.ado :conn_string => "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=source_db_file.mdb"

    @db_destination = Sequel.ado :conn_string => "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=destination_db_file.mdb"

    begin
        _copy_table :table_name
    ensure
        @db_source.disconnect
        @db_destination.disconnect
    end
end

def _copy_table table_name
    $logger.info "Import table #{table_name}"
    begin
        @db_destination[table_name].truncate
        # Load Data
        data = @db_source[table_name].select(@table_fields[table_name])
        # Import Data
        @db_destination[table_name].import(@table_fields[table_name], data, :commit_every => 50)
    rescue Exception => e
        $logger.error "Failed to import table #{table_name}, #{e.message}"
    else
        $logger.info "Table #{table_name} imported."
    end
end
```

I get this error:

```
OLE error code:80040E14 in Microsoft JET Database Engine
Syntax error (comma) in query expression
```

I tried some variants like the following:

```
# Import Data
@db_destination[table_name].import(@table_fields[table_name], @db_source[table_name], :commit_every => 50)
```

the result is big different. No data is exported, but I have no errors.

Comment: Why write the code? [Sequel can copy databases for you](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/bin_sequel_rdoc.html#label-Copy+Databases). Once it's done you can touch up anything necessary.

Comment: Because I need to import some specific tables only and drop / create them each morning. It is a scheduled task.

Comment: You're replicating one table to another DB daily then?

Comment: Then import some more thing from another source

Comment: Can you try `multi_insert` instead of `import`?